# How to set center of gravity on prefab child?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 3d model prefab in unity that I'm trying to add physics to. The issue is that the prefab was imported from auto desk and when that happened the pivot/center of gravity for all the child mesh objects was not where you would necessarily expect them. I've tried attaching a rigid body to the various child objects and setting the center of mass with a script but it doesn't seem to be working as I would expect. My method for setting the center of mass involved creating two child game objects at either end of the highlighted object and using the midpoint formula to a 'good enough' center of mass. Is there any way around this beyond rebuilding/re-importing the object?

Showing the off center pivot

[image]

Showing the weird center of mass

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CenterOfGravity : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public Transform[] centerPoints;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    void Start()
    {
        centerPoints = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();


        Transform center1 = Array.Find(centerPoints, elem => elem.name.Equals("Center1"));
        Transform center2 = Array.Find(centerPoints, elem => elem.name.Equals("Center2"));


        Vector3 center = (center1.localPosition + center2.localPosition)/2.0f;

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.ResetCenterOfMass();
        rb.centerOfMass = center;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){}
}
```

Comment: The second image still only shows us where the pivot of your rigidbody object is it doesn't really let us see where the center of mass is placed. Also the first image is of the parent object so it is quite hard to tell what exactly the expected vs the actual result is here ... In general it seems like all your objects pivots are placed "wrong" on the parent pivot ... but afaik Unity anyway by default uses the center of geometry (of the MeshRenderer. bounds) as default center of mass

Comment: My assumption is that the center of mass/pivot are the same since once the simulation is started the pivot point of the highlighted object comes to rest directly below the axis of rotation (same with the right object). The desired outcome is that the highlighted object would come to rest at a 90 degree angle straight down instead of a slant.

Comment: Afaik setting `rb.centerOfMass = center;` will **not** change the GameObject's pivot point and also the mesh data is most probably not translated in order to match that center .... The second image proves that your pivot is still exactly in the same spot, only your object rotated by 45° ...

Answer (score 0):

Every time I have to change the center off mass of an object, I create an empty child Game Object in the place where I want to be the center of mass.

After that, I set the center off mass of the object, to the local position of the new child object, something like that:

```
    public GameObject childObj, myObj;

    void Start()
    {
      myObj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().centerOfMass = childObj.transform.localPosition;
    }
```

**Edit:**

If you want to change the pivot of a GameObject, you need to do those things:

1-Create an empty game object and name it as "Pivot".

2-Place the pivot where you want the center of mass to be.

3-Asign your initial game object that you want to change the pivot as child of your new object called "Pivot".

Now the pivot of the initial game object should be the empty game object called pivot.

Comment: I did something similar except that I created two empty child game objects at either end and set the center of mass at the midpoint. In any case for whatever reason changing the center of mass seems to have no effect on the highlighted object.

Answer (score -1):

Some disclaimers first, AFAIK there's no way to do that in unity BUT! there is a workaround I came across when I had a similar issue. The thing is that I'm not quite sure what your work pipeline is, and this fix might be even worst than just modifying the meshes in auto desk and reimporting it.

The idea is to move your object temporarily to another game object, then modifying the broken pivot and bringing it back to the original object. The idea comes from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6qwjyypHcj8). It may work for you too!

Comment: a) Yes you can simply recalculate the pivot by transforming the original mesh vertices. b) If it is not possible than what would be [`Rigidbody.centerOfMass`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-centerOfMass.html) good for?